# TFS - .Net api to build, merge, associate workitems and more

Tags: .net, tfs

I'm going to admit right now, I'm still very much in the research phase of this potential project.  Currently I'm faced with several steps when it comes to moving code to integration:

- check-in
- merge from main code line to working code line
- fix conflicts
- merge from working code line to main code line
- create shelveset in main code line
- update work items to indicate various things

I'm wondering if there is a way to create a windows form to set everything up for the developer(s) and press a button and just let it rip?

I understand that TFS has an .Net API but I'm not sure where to begin.  Are the things I have list above even possible to do in the API?  Where are some good examples on how to accomplish these items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More or less, everything you mention is doable with TFS-SDK.
You can start studying from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb130146%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), another great resource is Shai Raiten's [series](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/shair/archive/2011/05/18/tfs-api-index-parts-1-to-37.aspx). 
What you are after looks similar to T.Arora's [work](http://geekswithblogs.net/TarunArora/archive/2011/06/26/tfs-2010-sdk-smart-merge-programmatically-create-your-own-merge.aspx), you can check it out as well.
In my personal opinion, you can't automate everything in the dev-process, simply because Development is far too complicated for that.
 Depending on your culture & process it can be safely assumed that several parts can get automated & if so - do automate!
Investing in learning the TFS-SDK is in my opinion a 'must', since it provides you with the means to explore the platform's abilities (at least your Build-master should know the basics).

Comment: Those look to be great resources.  Do you know the link to the SDK for TFS?

Comment: That's installed with VS. They are the assemblies under `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.*`